# How to allign a textView according to its center in Android

Tags: android

Very simply put, I want to allign a textView according to its center instead of its border, so lets say, when using android:layout_marginRight="50dp", instead of the right border being 50dp away, the center of the textView being 50dp away from the parent's right border. Here is my code for reference:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/breakfastStats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfastAdd"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightblack">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Carbohydrate"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fat"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
```

[image]

Comment: you should probably stop using relative layout entirely, you can achieve this by just using constraint layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using a GridLayout instead of a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin and padding value together for the TextView.

```
marginRight = "25dp"
paddingRight = "25dp"
gravity = "center"
```